# 1and1 htaccess errors

Tags: .htaccess

The commented out google redirect is working but the rest of the rules dont work at all.

it automatically gives me a 500 internal server error. This only happens on the 1and1 server.

```
RewriteEngine On
Options FollowSymLinks

# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.google.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

RewriteRule ^(ajax)/([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)$ http://mysite.com/index.php?ajax=$2 [r=301,nc] 

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)$ http://mysite.com/index.php?page=$1&subPage=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/$ http://mysite.com/index.php?page=$1&subPage=$2

RewriteRule ^repairs/([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]*)$ http://mysite.com/repairs-engine.php?page=repairs&subPage=$1&pitem=$2

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)$ http://mysite.com/index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/$ http://mysite.com/index.php?page=$1
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Very disappointing service of 1and1

Answer (score 1):

1. For exact error description you should check the Apache's error log.
2. What this pattern supposed to mean `[a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]` ?? It is definitely wrong. It should be `[a-zA-Z0-9\-]` -- *I'm pretty sure that this is **the reason** for error.*

**NOTES:**

1. If using `[NC]` flag, then no need to have `a-zA-Z` -- just `a-z` will be enough.
2. If doing rewrite (internal redirect, when URL changes in browser's address bar) and not proper redirect (301, 302 etc), then no need to use full domain name.
3. In any case, I suggest adding `[L]` flag to all rules -- it will speed up processing by tiny bit.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried not to escape the last dash in the char class block?

like this:

^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$

Comment: you may have meant to include all lower and upper case ascii letter, digits from 0 through 9 and a dash, maybe an underscore would be handy too like this:

Comment: This fixed the 500 error but now its dns page not found redirect to comcast ?cat=dnsr&con=ds&url=http

Comment: i do not understand what your comment means.  i am guessing tht the result is such a url that cannot be resolved.??